# Can I replace an existing receptacle with a Leviton USB receptacle?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I have this [Leviton USB product](http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/ProductDetail.jsp?partnumber=T5632-W&section=63676&minisite=10251.), which contains 1 hot terminal; 1 neutral terminal and 1 ground terminal.

I want it to replace a receptacle that has 2 hot terminals and 2 neutral terminals (along with the ground).  Can the new USB receptacle replace the existing one?

Comment: Check carefully - if the tab between the terminals (usually just the hot side) is broken/removed on the original outlet, there might be reason not to connect both wires to the new device. Particularly in kitchens, a multiwire branch circuit where the two hot wires are 240V with respect to each other is fairly common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the link you provided, Leviton has a product sheet with installation instructions. As they note in there, if you need to connect two wires each for line and neutral, you must use the backwire connections:

> To Side Wire (if more than one wire is required on a terminal, you cannot side wire and must use the backwire option)

What that means is that instead of wrapping the stripped wire end around the screw, instead you insert a straight portion of stripped wire into holes in the back. Sometimes those are spring clamped just by inserting them, but here it sounds like the screw will tighten a clamp onto the inserted wires.

You might be able to straighten your existing wires to do that, or cut and strip according to the instructions, and slide the pairs of wires under the clamps.

Comment: okay, thanks, that's what I really wanted to be sure about!

Comment: That's correct -- I just installed this outlet over the weekend. The backwire connection does have a clamp (it's not just a push-in) and it is designed to hold 2 wires at once.

Comment: @marcwenger, you can also use an extra piece of wire to make a pigtail to wire these receptacles. Either method is fine.

Comment: @mjohns - this outlet is so big that there may not be room in the box to make a pigtail, I have some boxes that are tight just for a GFCI and this USB outlet is much bigger than any modern GFCI I've seen.

Comment: @Johnny, I successfully pigtailed some in my house using deep boxes. You're right that it would be a challenge with a smaller box.